# passing  values (through listbox) between webpages in asp.net-c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, stringbuilder

**~/Admin/AdimHome.aspx.cs** C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>function Open() {");
     sb.Append(string.Format("window.open('Chat.aspx?rid={0}'", lstRooms.SelectedValue));
     sb.Append(", 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500');return false;");
     sb.Append("}</script>");

     if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock"))
     {
         ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock", sb.ToString());
     }

    lblFacultyNo.Text = Session["User_Id"].ToString();
    lblUserType.Text = Session["User_Type"].ToString();

    pnlChat.Visible = false;   
}
```

**~/Admin/Chat.aspx.cs page** C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["User_Id"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AdimHome.aspx");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["rid"]))
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AdminHome.aspx");

        txtMsg.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'btn')");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            hdnRoomID.Value = Request.QueryString["rid"];
            ChatRoom room = ChatEngine.GetRoom(hdnRoomID.Value);
            string prevMsgs = room.JoinRoom(Session["User_Id"].ToString(), Session["User_Id"].ToString());
            txt.Text = prevMsgs;
            foreach (string s in room.GetRoomUsersNames())
            {
                lstMembers.Items.Add(new ListItem(s, s));
            }

        }
    }
```

want to pass **lstRooms.SelectedValue** to **Chat.aspx.cs page** to check as per client request to differentiate their chat rooms:

```
sb.Append(string.Format("window.open('Chat.aspx?rid={0}'", lstRooms.SelectedValue));
```

onclicking the btnChat event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnChat" Runat="server" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick="JavaScript:Open()" OnClick="btnChat_Click" Text="Join Room" />
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Also, `StringBuilder` has an `AppendFormat()` method which will save you writing `String.Format` after your `sb.Append` call.

Comment: problem is that it automatically opens **AdminHome.aspx** instead of **Chat.aspx with reqsted rid**...see code on Chat.aspx.cs _Laod event...is there any wrong way to define?? plz help me

Comment: whats lstRooms? is it dropdown or ListBox?

Comment: why are you using OnClick="btnChat_Click" i dont think it is neeed. and is creating problems

Comment: Ste - not gives exactly error but it will redirect me on **AdminHome.aspx instead of Chat.aspx with reqsted rid...** i think it directle evaluate this line....                                  **if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["rid"]))
            Response.quer("~/Admin/AdminHome.aspx");** from chat.aspx.cs page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution to your problem could be if you want to change your code...

```
//Javascript function
function Open()
{
   var ddl = document.getElementbyId('<%= lstRooms.ClientID%>');
   var ddlvalue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
   Window.Open("Chat.aspx?rid=" + ddlvalue );
}
```

remove all the code for JS in pageload and put this on aspx page.
let me know if it solves

Comment: in your aspx page place it under <script language="text/javascript"></script> and see if it works and remember to comment the code in your page_load event of adminhome.aspx till lblFacultyNo.Text = Session["User_Id"].ToString();

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to open chat.aspx page, when you click on button to which you want to send the query string from listbox selected value? and tell me what is not working.

Comment: yes, i want to open chat.aspx page as per listbox selected value.... i did as u said the javascript on home.aspx page and commented till session of user_id....but i can't open a new window for that... do make any changes in chat.aspx.cs(C#) file or any othe else...

Comment: you want to run code behind code on button click too? because you have Onclick and onclient click both. If not type OnClientClick="Open();return false;" and check it works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10738/discussion-between-kamran-pervaiz-and-mack28)

Comment: let me explain i have **1 linkbutton** by clicking on that it displays a **listbox and button** as said above...when selecting any 1 value randomly and then click on join chat butoon which you are talking about... now i want to open new popup window with chat.aspx page....now tell me what i have to do ????